# Map a fbx model between 2 VertexPositionColor Positions

Tags: xna, 3d, xna-4.0

I have created a VertexPositionColor position and drew it in the XNA like this

```
VertexPositionColor[] backbone;
backbone = new VertexPositionColor[2];

backbone[0].Position = new Vector3(0, 22, 0);
backbone[0].Color = Color.Black;
backbone[1].Position = new Vector3(0, 10, 0);
backbone[1].Color = Color.Black;
```

In the draw method

```
graphics.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(PrimitiveType.LineList, backbone, 0, 1);
```

My question is, is it possible to map a 3d bone (Model exported as fbx) to these coordinates. or is there a much easier way to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, is possible to visualize model bones. This article http://www.digitalrune.com/Support/Blog/tabid/719/EntryId/129/Visualization-of-a-Model-Skeleton.aspx help you with it. Result can be seen for example on this my video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8SRPFsB6lc